# Using grep to find tag and get arbitrary string after it

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

So I have this pattern, the whole thing is one line

```
<img  itemprop="image"  class="hovered__image jsOpenGallery lazyload" data-src="//static.yellowpages.ca/ypca/ypui-6.65.0.0-20220419.0826/resources/images/serp/photo-gallery-icon.svg" alt="Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors"/><img  itemprop="image"  class="jsMerchantLogo lazyload" data-src="https://ssmscdn.yp.ca/image/resize/8bfbcba8-0a3e-48d3-b64b-16df5995779c/yp-serp-thumbnail/1.jpg" alt="Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors"/>
```

here I am using the expression "alt=" to find the tag and I need to get the name of the business after it like this from above code

```
alt="Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors"
```

The name can be anything, but it is always enclosed in " ". can I use grep to return something like `alt="business name"`

Comment: That works great, Thanks!

Comment: Mandatory [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5477531)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### htmlq

You can use **[htmlq](https://github.com/mgdm/htmlq)** (*Like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), but for HTML.*). Install it with [brew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install htmlq` and pipe your string to

```
| htmlq --attribute alt img
```

Check also for HTML [**pup**](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup), and [**xq**](https://github.com/jeffbr13/xq) for XML.

#### grep (PCREs)

A less elegant way ([you can't really parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4970442)) is to just use grep with `--perl-regexp` and `--only-matching`, with a regex using [lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```sh
| grep -Po "(?<= alt=\")[^\"]*"
```

Check also **[ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tackle it in a more structured manner, you could

- use `xmllint` to convert the input to valid XML (essentially adding a root element and replacing `&` characters by their entities)
- use `xmlstarlet` to select the `alt` tag
- (optionally) unescape the `&amp;` entity

ex. given

```
$ cat file
<img  itemprop="image"  class="hovered__image jsOpenGallery lazyload" data-src="//static.yellowpages.ca/ypca/ypui-6.65.0.0-20220419.0826/resources/images/serp/photo-gallery-icon.svg" alt="Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors"/><img  itemprop="image"  class="jsMerchantLogo lazyload" data-src="https://ssmscdn.yp.ca/image/resize/8bfbcba8-0a3e-48d3-b64b-16df5995779c/yp-serp-thumbnail/1.jpg" alt="Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors"/>
```

then

```
$ xmllint --html --xmlout --dropdtd file 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//img/@alt' -n | xmlstarlet unesc
Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors
Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors
```

If you have kislyuk's [yq: Command-line YAML/XML/TOML processor - jq wrapper for YAML, XML, TOML documents](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq#yq-command-line-yamlxmltoml-processor---jq-wrapper-for-yaml-xml-toml-documents) you can use `xq` instead of `xmlstarlet` - however the input still needs to be massaged into valid XML:

```
$ xmllint --html --xmlout --dropdtd file 2>/dev/null | xq '.. | .img? | .[]? | ."@alt"'
"Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors"
"Drain King Plumbers - Plumbers & Plumbing Contractors"
```